# How to pass a Dictionary from a viewController to a DetailViewController?

Tags: swift

Inside my model is a dictionary named

`var detailStock: Dictionary<String, StockInfoDetailed>?`

StockInfoDetailed is a class I made to define attributes of an API such as open, close, high, low.

Currently in my prepare for segue, I have passed basic stock information but need the detailStock information also.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dvc = segue.destination as? StockDetailViewController{
            dvc.myStock = myModel.currentStocks![(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }
```

How would I pass my detailStock information to my detail view controller? Currently my keys are time slots at different intervals using 
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Declare one object with same data type Dictionary? inside StockDetailViewController

StockDetailViewController.swift

```
var myDetailStock: Dictionary<String, StockInfoDetailed>?
```

Set value of that object in prepareForSegue()

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dvc = segue.destination as? StockDetailViewController{
            dvc.myStock = myModel.currentStocks![(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
            dvc.myDetailStock = myModel.detailStock![(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }
```